# Nested inline elements with Jade

Tags: pug

I'm trying to render properly this chunck of html code in Jade

```
<h1>Hello<small> world</small></h1>
```

unfortunately everything I tried it doesn't work.

I have tried putting `small` inline but it doesn't work. I have tried to put small in a new line but in that way small is not nested in h1 tags

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have found this solution and it works. Since Jade 1.0 the nested inline tags are supported

```
h1 Hello #[small world]
```

Answer (score 10):

Starting with [Jade 1.0](http://jade-lang.com/history/#1-0-0-2013-12-22), circa December 2013, inline tags are supported using the following syntax:

> `#[tag(attribute='value') lorem ipsum]`

Using your HTML example of:

```
<h1>Hello <small>world</small></h1>
```

Could be rewritten in Jade as:

```
h1 Hello #[small world]
```

---

While not as popular — and certainly not better — you can also mix and max Jade tags with regular HTML, such as:

```
h1 Hello <small>world</small>
```

The [Jade Playground](http://learnjade.com/playground/) is a great place to try out new techniques!

Answer (score 4):

Beside of inline elements you can also use HTML chunks after using the first jade element generating syntax. So

```
h1 Hello <small>world</small>
```

will also render as

```
<h1>Hello <small>world</small></h1>
```